# Upper bound of probability of Gaussian distribution in an interval?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics

Suppose $Z$ is a Gaussian distribution $N(0,\sigma^2)$. Is there a formula of upper bound for $P(Z\in [a,b])$, or do we know this probability is integral with respect to $\sigma\in \mathbf{R}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The probability is given by $$ P(Z\in[a,b]) =\int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)}dx$$ i.e. you integrate the density of the $N(0,\sigma^2)$ over the interval. You can also substitute $u = x/\sigma$ into the formula and get $$ P(Z\in[a,b]) = \int_{a/\sigma}^{b/\sigma} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-u^2/2}du$$
and this in turn can be expressed as $$ P(Z\in[a,b]) = \Phi(b/\sigma)-\Phi(a/\sigma)$$ where $\Phi(x) = \int_{-\infty}^xe^{-u^2/2}du/\sqrt{2\pi}$ is the standard normal cumulative.

As for how to get an upper bound, it really depends how good of an upper bound you want and where $a$ and $b$ are. Usually you'd just compute it exactly since the normal cumulative is usually available.

One crude way for $0<a<b$ would be to notice that $e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)} \le e^{-a^2/(2\sigma^2)}$ for $x\in (a,b)$ so you have $$ P(Z\in[a,b]) =\int_a^b \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-x^2/(2\sigma^2)}dx \le \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-a^2/(2\sigma^2)}\int_a^bdx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-a^2/(2\sigma^2)}(b-a).$$ This works best when $b-a$ is small relative to $\sigma.$ This obviously doesn't work at all in the important case where $b=\infty$

Comment: Suppose $a<0<b$ are fixed finite constants. Let $\sigma^2=t.$ I wonder if $f(t):=P(Z_t\in [a,b])=\int^b_a\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi t}}e^{-\frac{x^2}{2t}}dx$ is integral over all $t\in (0,\infty).$ But it seems not if we use Fubini's theorem by interchanging the order of integrals.

Comment: @Connor I have no idea what you mean by 'is integral over all $t\in(0\infty)$'. It's a function of $t.$

Comment: Sorry, I mean "is integral over $(0,\infty)$".

Comment: @Connor still have no idea what you mean by that. Like is an integer? That can't be it?

Comment: I mean if $\int_0^\infty f(t) dt$ is finite, if $f$ is defined as above and $Z_t=N(0,t)=N(0,\sigma^2)$.

Comment: @Connor Oh you mean 'integrable'. No I don't think so. Say you have $a=-1$ and $b=1.$ Then as $t$ gets large the exponential factor won't matter in the integral so the $Z_t$ will go like $1/\sqrt{t}$ for $t$ large.

Answer (score 0):

If $b>a$ then the upper bound of integration is $b$. As area under a curve can be measured by integral and we know that the probability is some area under a curve, therefore we do know that probability is integral with respect to $x$.